# Convert a sequence of chars into their respective int

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to do a program in C that the user gives an input as: "one hundred ninety nine" and the output will be 199 this for numbers with three digits (until hundred).
But I only have this to convert from 1-9 and I don't know how can I implement for bigger numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 int main() {
     char numbers[10][10] = {"zero", "one" , "two", "three","four",  "five", "six", "seven","eight", "nine"};
        char input[100], word[10], *ptr, *tmp;
        int i, len, value;
        int values[9];
        /* get the number in words from user */
        printf("Enter number in word:\n");
        fgets(input, 100, stdin);
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
        tmp = input;
        while (1) {
        /* move pointer to the space to extract word by word */
        ptr = strchr(tmp, ' ');
        if (ptr != NULL) {
            len = ptr - tmp;
            strncpy(word, tmp, len);
            word[len] = '\0';
            tmp = ptr + 1;
            } else {
                    /* last word in the given string */
                    len = strlen(tmp);
                    strncpy(word, tmp, len);
                    word[len] = '\0';
                        }
                     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                     /* word to number conversion */
                    if (strcasecmp(word, numbers[i]) == 0) {
                        value = (value * 10) + i;
                        break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!ptr)
                        break;
                     }
        /* print the number */
        printf("Value in number is %d\n", value);
        int iN = 9;
        int arr[iN];
        while (iN--) {
         arr[iN]=value%10;
         value/=10;
        }
        printf("Value: %i", arr[0]);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: I guess you will have to write a compiler to solve this problem, I think you can get a c program to do this, but it would take you some time.

Comment: Does your input always three digits or you need to support two digits also? What are the min and max numbers you need to support?

Comment: @JVMATL Off-by-1.  Your comment is about `input[strlen(input) - 0] = '\0';`.  OP is using `input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';` to lop off the `'\n'` and it is hacker exploitable as `input[0]` may be 0.

Comment: `len = ptr - tmp;
            strncpy(word, tmp, len);
            word[len] = '\0';` is UB with input like `"abcdefghij"`.  Hope your users only enter expected input.

Answer (score 0):

The following function analyses the next token, converts it to an int and skips it. By repeatedly calling the function you can parse any number. It is in Dutch but the meaning should be clear:

```
static int lookupnum(const char *s, const char **s2, long *num)
{
    long t;

    if (strncmp(s, "nul", 3)==0)
    {
        *num= 0; *s2= s+3; return(TRUE);
    }
    else if (t=(strncmp(s, "en",      2)==0?s+=2,0:     // "and"
                strncmp(s, "één",     3)==0?s+=3,1:     // numbers
                strncmp(s, "eén",     3)==0?s+=3,1:
                strncmp(s, "een",     3)==0?s+=3,1:
                strncmp(s, "twee",    4)==0?s+=4,2:
                strncmp(s, "drie",    4)==0?s+=4,3:
                strncmp(s, "vier",    4)==0?s+=4,4:
                strncmp(s, "vijf",    4)==0?s+=4,5:
                strncmp(s, "zes",     3)==0?s+=3,6:
                strncmp(s, "zeven",   5)==0?s+=5,7:
                strncmp(s, "acht",    4)==0?s+=4,8:
                strncmp(s, "negen",   5)==0?s+=5,9:
                strncmp(s, "tien",    4)==0?s+=4,10:
                strncmp(s, "elf",     3)==0?s+=3,11:
                strncmp(s, "twaalf",  6)==0?s+=6,12:
                strncmp(s, "dertien", 7)==0?s+=7,13:
                strncmp(s, "veertien",8)==0?s+=8,14:
                strncmp(s, "twintig", 7)==0?s+=7,20:
                strncmp(s, "dertig",  6)==0?s+=6,30:
                strncmp(s, "veertig", 7)==0?s+=7,40:
                strncmp(s, "vijftig", 7)==0?s+=7,50:
                strncmp(s, "zestig",  6)==0?s+=6,60:
                strncmp(s, "zeventig",8)==0?s+=8,70:
                strncmp(s, "tachtig", 7)==0?s+=7,80:
                strncmp(s, "negentig",8)==0?s+=8,90:
                strncmp(s, "honderd", 7)==0?s+=7,100:
                strncmp(s, "duizend", 7)==0?s+=7,1000:
                strncmp(s, "miljoen", 7)==0?s+=7,1000000:
                strncmp(s, "miljard", 7)==0?s+=7,1000000000:0))
    {
        *num= t;
        *s2 = s;
        return(TRUE);    // return success
    }
    else
        return(FALSE);   // return error
}
```

Example: "driehonderdeenendertigduizendzeshondertweeentwintig"

Or: "six hunderd twenty thousand fourhundered and twenty" (need to manage spaces in English: any larger number following a smaller number implies multiply, it seems?)

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solve this would be, split your input as tokens and parse each token in the reverse order and accumulate the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUM_WORDS   10
#define MAX_INPUT_LEN   128
#define ARRAY_SIZE(a)   (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

enum digit_state {
    UNITS,
    TENS,
    HUNDREDS,
    MAX_STATE
};

int get_numerical_value(const char **array, unsigned int length, char *token)
{
    int i;
    int val = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (!strcmp(array[i], token)) {
            val = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return val;
}

unsigned int string2num(char *str)
{
    int i;
    int n;
    int num_words;
    unsigned int result;
    unsigned int state;
    char *token;
    char *words[MAX_NUM_WORDS];
    char input[MAX_INPUT_LEN];
    const char *units[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    const char *tens[] = {"zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

    // save input
    memset(input, 0, MAX_INPUT_LEN);
    strncpy(input, str, strlen(str));

    // get each token, allocate memory and save them in an array
    num_words = 0;
    token = strtok(input, " ");
    while (token) {
        int len = strlen(token) + 1;

        words[num_words] = malloc(len);
        memset(words[num_words], 0, len);

        strncpy(words[num_words], token, len);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        num_words++;
    }

    result = 0;
    state = UNITS;
    n = num_words;

    // process each token in the reverse order
    while (n--) {
        int val;

        if (state == UNITS) {
            val = get_numerical_value(units, ARRAY_SIZE(units), words[n]);
            if (val > 0)
                result += val;
            else
                // units digit missing so ignore this word
                ++n;

            state++;
        } else if (state == TENS) {
            val = get_numerical_value(tens, ARRAY_SIZE(tens), words[n]);
            if (val > 0)
                result += val*10;
            else
                ++n;    // tens digit missing so ignore this word

            state++;
        } else if (state == HUNDREDS) {
            val = 0;

            if (!strcmp(words[n], "hundred"))
                val = get_numerical_value(units, ARRAY_SIZE(units), words[--n]);

            result += val*100;
            state++;
        } else if (state == MAX_STATE) {
            break;
        }
    }

    while (num_words--)
        free(words[num_words]);

    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *input[] = {
        "one hundred fifty four",
        "two hundred thirty",
        "eighty one",
        "five",
        "zero",
        "forty",
    };

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(input); ++i) {
        unsigned int val = string2num(input[i]);
        printf("%s: %u\n", input[i], val);
    }
}
```

This is general idea, you can improve it further and depending upon your inputs you need to handle all corner cases.